# Как сделать так, чтоб содержимое списка ListView было (по стандарту) прокручено вниз?

Tags: android, xml, listview, прокрутка

Есть активити, в котором показывается список сообщений, который можно листать вниз и вверх. Как сделать так, чтоб этот список был прокручен вниз по стандарту (автоматически) ??.

Содержимое **message.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tequila.online.radio.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clouds" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messageListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"

        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="100dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/your_message"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textColorLink="@color/secondary_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:elevation="7dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/send_message" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте этот атрибут в `ListView`:

```
<ListView 
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
...
></ListView>
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9988300/3978990

Comment: большое спасибо!